# Difference between np.dot and np.multiply with np.sum in binary cross-entropy loss calculation

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, sum, difference

I have tried the following code but didn't find the difference between **np.dot** and **np.multiply with np.sum**

Here is **np.dot** code

```
logprobs = np.dot(Y, (np.log(A2)).T) + np.dot((1.0-Y),(np.log(1 - A2)).T)
print(logprobs.shape)
print(logprobs)
cost = (-1/m) * logprobs
print(cost.shape)
print(type(cost))
print(cost)
```

Its output is

```
(1, 1)
[[-2.07917628]]
(1, 1)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
[[ 0.693058761039 ]]
```

Here is the code for **np.multiply with np.sum**

```
logprobs = np.sum(np.multiply(np.log(A2), Y) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A2)))
print(logprobs.shape)         
print(logprobs)
cost = - logprobs / m
print(cost.shape)
print(type(cost))
print(cost)
```

Its output is

```
()
-2.07917628312
()
<class 'numpy.float64'>
0.693058761039
```

I'm unable to understand the type and shape difference whereas the result value is same in both cases

Even in the case of squeezing former code  **cost value become same as later but type remains same**

```
cost = np.squeeze(cost)
print(type(cost))
print(cost)
```

output is

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
0.6930587610394646
```

Comment: `np.sum` returns a scalar, `np.dot` doesn't...

Comment: To get a concrete answer you should probably provide the shapes of the input arrays. In general, what you see is that `np.sum` by default always sums over the whole input and returns a scalar. `np.dot` only sums over one axis (which in your case seems to be the only one) and preserves dimensions.

Comment: What you're doing is calculating `binary cross-entropy loss` and both approaches that you tried are *equivalent* which is why you get same result. It's not clear what your actual question is about.

Comment: Actually I was looking for a scalar value in answer of **np.dot**

Comment: @AsadShakeel I added more explanation to it. Please check my answer :)

Comment: To get a scalar value you need to use 1d arrays, not the 2d ones.

Comment: np.multiply(a,b) gives a vector of (ai x bi), while  np.dot gives the sum of those vector elements, so your code shows the equivalence  `np.sum(np.multiply(a,b))=np.dot(a,b)` .Incidentally a*b will give the same as np.multiply(a,b)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

What you're doing is calculating the [**binary cross-entropy loss**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy#Cross-entropy_loss_function_and_logistic_regression) which measures how bad the predictions (here: `A2`) of the model are when compared to the true outputs (here: `Y`).

Here is a reproducible example for your case, which should explain why you get a scalar in the second case using `np.sum`

```
In [88]: Y = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

In [89]: A2 = np.array([[0.8, 0.2, 0.95, 0.92, 0.01, 0.93, 0.1, 0.02]])

In [90]: logprobs = np.dot(Y, (np.log(A2)).T) + np.dot((1.0-Y),(np.log(1 - A2)).T)

# `np.dot` returns 2D array since its arguments are 2D arrays
In [91]: logprobs
Out[91]: array([[-0.78914626]])

In [92]: cost = (-1/m) * logprobs

In [93]: cost
Out[93]: array([[ 0.09864328]])

In [94]: logprobs = np.sum(np.multiply(np.log(A2), Y) + np.multiply((1 - Y), np.log(1 - A2)))

# np.sum returns scalar since it sums everything in the 2D array
In [95]: logprobs
Out[95]: -0.78914625761870361
```

Note that the [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) sums along *only the inner dimensions* which match here `(1x8) and (8x1)`. So, the `8`s will be gone during the dot product or matrix multiplication yielding the result as `(1x1)` which is just a *scalar* but returned as 2D array of shape `(1,1)`.

---

Also, most importantly note that here [`np.dot` is **exactly same** as doing `np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) since the inputs are 2D arrays (i.e. matrices)

```
In [107]: logprobs = np.matmul(Y, (np.log(A2)).T) + np.matmul((1.0-Y),(np.log(1 - A2)).T)

In [108]: logprobs
Out[108]: array([[-0.78914626]])

In [109]: logprobs.shape
Out[109]: (1, 1)
```

---

#### Return result as a *scalar* value

[`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) or [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) returns whatever the resulting array shape would be, based on input arrays. Even with `out=` argument it's not possible to return a *scalar*, if the inputs are 2D arrays. However, we can use [`np.asscalar()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.asscalar.html) on the result to convert it to a scalar if the result array is of shape `(1,1)` (or more generally a *scalar* value wrapped in an nD array)

```
In [123]: np.asscalar(logprobs)
Out[123]: -0.7891462576187036

In [124]: type(np.asscalar(logprobs))
Out[124]: float
```

---

> *ndarray* of size 1 to *scalar* value

```
In [127]: np.asscalar(np.array([[[23.2]]]))
Out[127]: 23.2

In [128]: np.asscalar(np.array([[[[23.2]]]]))
Out[128]: 23.2
```

Comment: Can't we get scalar value just using `np.dot()` in this case?
Because it is giving same answer as `np.multiply()` with `np.sum()`.

Comment: @AsadShakeel added a hack to convert the result to scalar :)

Comment: Thank you! I'd upvote you more than once if I could :)

Comment: Nice explanation. Saved lot of time.

Answer (score 96):

`np.dot` is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two matrices.

```
|A B| . |E F| = |A*E+B*G A*F+B*H|
|C D|   |G H|   |C*E+D*G C*F+D*H|
```

Whereas `np.multiply` does an [element-wise multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) of two matrices.

```
|A B| ⊙ |E F| = |A*E B*F|
|C D|   |G H|   |C*G D*H|
```

When used with `np.sum`, the result being equal is merely a coincidence.

```
>>> np.dot([[1,2], [3,4]], [[1,2], [2,3]])
array([[ 5,  8],
       [11, 18]])
>>> np.multiply([[1,2], [3,4]], [[1,2], [2,3]])
array([[ 1,  4],
       [ 6, 12]])

>>> np.sum(np.dot([[1,2], [3,4]], [[1,2], [2,3]]))
42
>>> np.sum(np.multiply([[1,2], [3,4]], [[1,2], [2,3]]))
23
```

Comment: what about just using `*` to multiply two matrices?

Comment: Using the `*` to multiply the matrices also does element-wise multiplicaiton, like the ⊙ and `np.multiply` operator.

Comment: hey, can you please explain what np.matmul() does

Comment: @Avnishkumar It performs a matrix multiplication. Please see my answer above for more explanation!

Answer (score 4):

If `Y` and `A2` are (1,N) arrays, then `np.dot(Y,A.T)` will produce a (1,1) result.  It is doing a matrix multiplication of a (1,N) with a (N,1).  The `N's` are summed, leaving the (1,1).

With `multiply` the result is (1,N).  Sum all values, and the result is a scalar.

If `Y` and `A2` were (N,) shaped (same number of elements, but 1d), the `np.dot(Y,A2)` (no `.T`) would also produce a scalar.  From `np.dot` documentation:

> For 2-D arrays it is equivalent to matrix multiplication, and for 1-D arrays to inner product of vectors
>
> Returns the dot product of a and b. If a and b are both scalars or both 1-D arrays then a scalar is returned; otherwise an array is returned.

`squeeze` reduces all size 1 dimensions, but still returns an array.  In `numpy` an array can have any number of dimensions (from 0 to 32).  So a 0d array is possible.  Compare the shape of `np.array(3)`, `np.array([3])` and `np.array([[3]])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
In this example it just not a coincidence. Lets take an example we have two (1,3) and (1,3) matrices. 
// Lets code 

import numpy as np

x1=np.array([1, 2, 3]) // first array
x2=np.array([3, 4, 3]) // second array

//Then 

X_Res=np.sum(np.multiply(x1,x2)) 
// will result 20 as it will be calculated as - (1*3)+(2*4)+(3*3) , i.e element wise
// multiplication followed by sum.

Y_Res=np.dot(x1,x2.T) 

// in order to get (1,1) matrix) from a dot of (1,3) matrix and //(1,3) matrix we need to //transpose second one. 
//Hence|1 2 3| * |3|
//               |4| = |1*3+2*4+3*3| = |20|
//               |3|
// will result 20 as it will be (1*3)+(2*4)+(3*3) , i.e. dot product of two matrices

print X_Res //20

print Y_Res //20
```