# optimize.fmin_tnc is not giving right answer in scipy.optimize?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, machine-learning, optimization, scipy

I am implementing Andrew ng's machine learning course in python. In programming exercise 2, on the first question, I am getting write answers for cost function and gradient but when calculation optimised theta, I am getting a disastrous answer!

I have already tried my best but not able to find the error

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def cost_compute(  theta,x, y):
    J = (-1/m) * np.sum(np.multiply(Y, np.log(sigmoid(X @ theta))) 
        + np.multiply((1-Y), np.log(1 - sigmoid(X @ theta))))
    return J

[m, n] = X.shape
X = np.hstack( (np.ones((m,1)) , X) )
Y = Y[:, np.newaxis]
theta = np.zeros((n+1,1))

def grad( theta, X, Y):
    temp = (1/m) * X.T @ (sigmoid(X @ theta) - Y)  
    return temp

temp = opt.fmin_tnc(func = cost_compute, x0 = theta.flatten() , fprime = grad , args = (X, Y.flatten()))

print(temp)
```

the expected cost is 0.693 and I am getting it.
The expected grad is also exactly the same as actual answer.
But the optimized theta i am getting is array([4.42735730e-05, 5.31690927e-03, 4.98646266e-03], giving me the new cost around 60! (instead of 0.203)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests by changing shapes of arrays, flattening it, reshaping it but nothing worked.

Since we were inputting a one dimension theta in fmin_tnc by flattening the theta, so i thought of changing the gradient function assuming that it will receive a single dimension theta instead of 3*1.

Earlier, it was

```
def grad( theta, X, Y):
    temp = (1/m) * X.T @ (sigmoid(X @ theta) - Y)  
    return temp
```

Now, it is

```
def grad( theta, X, Y):
    temp = (1/m) * (X.T @ (sigmoid(X @ theta[:,np.newaxis]) - Y))  
    return temp
```

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `np.sum` together with `np.multiply` instead of using e.g. `np.dot`, these operations are in general not equivalent.

The `np.multiply` operation calculates the elementwise product,  while `np.dot` calculates the proper matrix product, see [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48201957/5625981) by Anuj Gautam:

> `np.dot` is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of two matrices.
>
> ```
> |A B| . |E F| = |A*E+B*G A*F+B*H|
> |C D|   |G H|   |C*E+D*G C*F+D*H|
> ```
>
> Whereas `np.multiply` does an [element-wise
>   multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))
>   of two matrices.
>
> ```
> |A B| ⊙ |E F| = |A*E B*F|
> |C D|   |G H|   |C*G D*H|
> ```

To calculate the cross entropy loss, the matrix multiplication is needed.

Changing your cost function to

```
def cost_compute(  theta, X, Y):
    J = (-1/m) * (np.dot(Y.T, np.log(sigmoid(X @ theta))) 
        + np.dot((1-Y).T, np.log(1 - sigmoid(X @ theta))))
    return J
```

results in the desired result for me:

```
>> cost_compute(temp[0], X, Y)
array([0.2034977])
```

In addition, the case of your arguments `x` and `y` of the `cost_compute` function is wrong, as you use the capitalized versions `X` and `Y` inside the function.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the capitalisation error man.  But using sum and multiply wasn't wrong in this specific case as Y and sigmoid have shapes m*1, so if I was to use dot product then I am required to do this  ``` Y.T @ np.log(sigmoid(X @ theta))```